# Using Java Concurrent Collections in Scala

Tags: java, scala, concurrency

It seems like Scala is lacking all the concurrent collections that Java provides.  When I looked at the [JavaConverters.scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html) it seems to only convert non-concurrent collections + concurrent Map.  Is there a way to do this in Scala?

```
List<String> synlist = Collections.synchronizedList(list);

//call remove from multiple threads

synlist.remove(....)
```

Update

Not using actors, the recommend, similar, question and answers is not going to work in my case.  After digging around in the source code, the line below will work.  It seems like `JavaConverters.asScala` [will call underlying collection](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/JavaConversions.scala).

`Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList()).asScala`

Comment: Simple answer: don't! `Collections.synchronizedList(list)` is terribly naive and very slow - it's not a _concurrent_ `Collection` it's a **synchronized** one.

Comment: @BoristheSpider In my case, performance doesn't matter, I am after thread-safety.